# Show each individual record from different table using join in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table name as tblinvoices,tblinvoicepaymentrecords,tblcreditnote

tblinvoices

```
id | clientid |  date  |  total
  --------------------------------
  357    454    20-05-2019
```

tblcreditnote

```
 id | projectid | subtotal |datecreated
  --------------------------------------
   2    357          300       12-05-2019
   4    357          150       16-06-2019
```

tblinvoicepaymentrecords

```
 id | invoiceid | amount
  ------------------------
   1    357         100
```

I want to get tblinvoicepaymentrecords data and tblcreditnote record in separate row .

My query is

```
SELECT xp.clientid, xp.id invoiceid, xp.date,xp.total amount_raised, 
  tblcreditnote.subtotal as credit,xs.amount,
  xp.datecreated as cndate 
  from  tblinvoices xp 
  right join tblcreditnote on tblcreditnote.project_id = xp.id
  right join(select amount,id,invoiceid from tblinvoicepaymentrecords)xs on 
   xs.invoiceid=xp.id
  WHERE xp.status NOT IN( 5,6 ) AND xp.clientid=454
```

But here the result of both table data in one row.

[image]

Here i want to get each table data in separate row.

Comment: Joins are horiziontal  UNIONs are vertical . Please add your desired output rather than the not desired output.

Comment: or on the other words: `join` means "join to this row" not "add next row", so you cannot add a row by using `join`

Comment: So how can i show tblinvoicepaymentrecords record in one row and tblcreditnote record in another two rows.

Comment: UNION is a big clue..